# pandas fillna datetime column with timezone now

Tags: pandas, datetime, python-3.6

I have a pandas datetime column with `None` values which I would like to fill with `datetime.now()` in a specific timezone.

This is my MWE dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'end': "2017-07-01 12:00:00"},
    {'end': "2017-07-02 18:13:00"},
    {'end': None},
    {'end': "2017-07-04 10:45:00"}
])
```

If I fill with `fillna`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['end']).fillna(datetime.now())
```

The result is a series with expected dtype: `datetime64[ns]`. But when I specify the timezone, for example:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['end']).fillna(
    datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))
```

This returns a series with dtype: `object`

Comment: What is desired output? Do you need mixed timezones in column? utc with `US/Pacific` ?

Comment: Note that doing this will convert all timestamps to that timezone, the final result is correct, if you look at any specific element value, it's a timestamp with the desired timezone information. It's just that numpy doesn't have a dtype that supports this but the dtype is timestamp and numerical operations are supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need convert `date` to `to_datetime` in `fillna`:

```
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df['end'] = df['end'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))))
print (df)
                                end
0               2017-07-01 12:00:00
1               2017-07-02 18:13:00
2  2017-07-04 03:35:08.499418-07:00
3               2017-07-04 10:45:00

print (df['end'].apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
3    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
Name: end, dtype: object
```

But still `dtype` is not `datetime64`:

```
print (df['end'].dtype)
object
```

I think solution is pass paramter `utc` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> **utc** : boolean, default None
>
> Return UTC DatetimeIndex if True (converting any tz-aware datetime.datetime objects as well).

```
df['end'] = df['end'].fillna(pd.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], utc=True)

#print (df)

print (df['end'].apply(type))
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
2    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
3    <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
Name: end, dtype: object

print (df['end'].dtypes)
datetime64[ns]
```

And final solution from [comment of OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903292/pandas-fillna-datetime-column-with-timezone-now/44903630?noredirect=1#comment76786139_44903630):

```
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end']).dt.tz_localize('US/Pacific')
df['end'] = df['end'].fillna(pd.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))

print (df.end.dtype)
datetime64[ns, US/Pacific]
```

Comment: this returns the UTC now instead of in the specified timezone

Comment: Yes, exactly. If need datetime64 then is problem have datetime64 dtypes if some dates contains timezones and another not. It works perfectly if all dates have timezones or there is no timezone information.

Comment: Also I find this [warning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones) - `Warning

It is incorrect to pass a timezone directly into the datetime.datetime constructor (e.g., datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, tz=timezone('US/Eastern')). Instead, the datetime needs to be localized using the the localize method on the timezone. `

Comment: thanks! solved by defining `to_datetime` with timezone: `df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end']).dt.tz_localize('US/Pacific')` and then `.fillna`

Comment: Supeeer, I add it to answer.